# Jquery Ajax fires error callback on first load of application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net5

I have an odd one here.  I am doing an ajax call back to my action method, its quite a simple call and I am always passing back a JSON object in the action method.  However, when I have built my application and run it locally, the first time the ajax request is made, the error callback is executed.  This callback is being fired before the request has returned anything, I can put a breakpoint in action method, the breakpoint is hit, I leave it as paused but error is fired.  On the next ajax request, everything works fine, breakpoint is hit, nothing happens until I continue and then success is returned.

The error details when first selected are

```
xhr = Object {readyState: 0, responseJSON: undefined, status: 0, statusText: "error"}, ajaxOptions = "error", thrownerror = ""
```

My ajax call is as follows

```
jquery.ajax({
    url: "ReportSetting/SaveSetting",
    data: {
        reportSettings: this.ReportSettings
    },
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(partialViewData) {
        alert("Settings saved");
        return true;
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("ERROR SAVING SETTINGS");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Here is my action method

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SaveSetting(int companyId, IList<ReportSetting> reportSettings)
    {
        _reportSettingsService.SaveSettings(companyId, reportSettings);

        return Json(reportSettings);
    }
```

And razor view of button

```
<a type="submit" class="btn btn-success" type="button" data-bind="click: SaveButtonClicked" asp-controller="ReportSetting" asp-action="Index">Save</a>
```

This occurs on Chrome.  On IE no alert appears but the action method does run.  I am running .net5.  Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: where are you including the code? Is it supposed to run at page load, or at another time?

Comment: Its executed on a button click event

Comment: if that's the case, then it _can't_ be running at page load...so either your statement "It's execute on a button click" is not true, or the description of the problem is inaccurate. I think maybe you should share all of the script code for the page, not just the function.

Comment: I can see why that was misleading so have edited the post.  The error occurs the first time I call the ajax request once I have started my application.  All other calls subsequently are fine.

Comment: ok first step is to have your error function report the error more clearly. You might also see something by looking in the developer tools (in the console and the network tab). So amend your error function to: `function (jQXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   alert("An error occurred whilst trying to contact the server: " + jQXHR.status + " " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
  }` and then see what it reports

Comment: jQHR.status = 0, textStatus = "error", errorThrown=""

Comment: on the first request, is it sending the correct data to the controller? I'm wondering if some sort of exception is occuring relating to the data not mapping to the model. .net is not always very good at reporting those properly.

Comment: another thing...is your button a "submit" button (i.e. `<input type="submit">` or `<button type="submit">` (or just `<button>` with no type specified)? If so, are you preventing a postback when you handle the click event? e.g. `$("#myButton").click(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); //then the ajax call });`

Comment: Yep the correct values are being passed to controller.  Have attached controller and razor view of button to this post

Comment: what about my second point about the submit button? Looking at it, I think you need event.preventDefault() otherwise you may be getting a postback at the same time as your ajax. Can you show the whole JS click handler funciton please.

Comment: OK, have fixed it.  Thanks for your help.  In JS handler, the only extra bit was return true at bottom of handler.  As the request is asynchronous, then the anchor element would reload and guess this was causing problems whilst request was running.  Have changed the handler to return false (so effectively doing preventDefault), and in the success callback I call location.reload

Comment: glad you fixed it. out of interest, why do you need to reload after the success? surely that defeats the point of using ajax - you might as well just do the whole thing in a postback??

Comment: Good point, I am probably going to change it to navigate to another action method on success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have fixed this now.  My handler was returning true, so I think anchor tag was reloading as request was being fired so request getting in a muddle.  I have now changed it to return false and in success handler I refresh the page